# ListView A inside ListView B is not defined in a window that loads with a loader qml

Tags: qt, listview, qml, loader

I have a Vertical `ListView` nested in a horizontal `Listview` like below (it is generic code because the real code is too long and I wanted to give an idea of what I want to do )  :

```
ApplicationWindow{
       id:appwindow
       ............
       Item{
        id:dayView
        ...........
        ListView{
            id:dayCalendar 
            orientation: Qt.Horizontal
            model:31
            delegate: Item{
            ...............
            ListView{
                id:daylistView
                orientation: Qt.Vertical
                model:24
                delegate:Item{
                     id:hourItem
                     property string hourTime:hourweeklistviewLabel
                     property string notetaking:notesLabe 
                     .............
                     MouseArea{
                          anchors.fill:parent
                          onClicked:{
                          windowLoader.active =true
                          daylistView.currentIndex=index

                          }
                     }  
                     Rectangle{}
                     Label{
                       id:hourweeklistviewLabel
                     }
                     Label{
                       id:notesLabel                                        
                       anchors.left:hourweeklistviewLabel.right
                       anchors.leftMargin: 30
                       text:""
                     }//Label
                    }//delegate:Item
                   }//ListView
                  } //delegate:Item
                 }//ListView
                }//Item
```

There is also a loader that loads a window when I click inside `MouseArea` inside the vertical ListView:

```
Loader {
    id:windowLoader
    focus: true
    active:false
    sourceComponent: Window{
        id:inputWin
        title:"Enter Note"
        width:500
        height:300
        visible:true

        onClosing:{
            windowLoader.active=false
            daylistView.currentIndex = calendarMonth.selectedDate.getDate() === new Date().getDate()
                    && calendarMonth.selectedDate.getMonth() === new Date().getMonth()?getHour():12
        }
        TextField {
            id:title
            x:50
            y:20
            placeholderText :'Enter Note'
            text:daylistView.currentItem.notetaking.text
        }
        TextField{
            id:timeDate

            anchors.horizontalCenter: title.horizontalCenter
            anchors.top:title.bottom
            anchors.topMargin:10
            placeholderText :  calendarMonth.selectedDate.getDate() +"-"
                   + (calendarMonth.selectedDate.getMonth()+1)+"-"
                   + calendarMonth.selectedDate.getFullYear() + " "
                   + daylistView.currentItem.hourTime.text +":00"
                }

            Button {
                 id: button
                 text: qsTr("Add Note")
                 anchors.centerIn:parent

                 onClicked: {
                       if (title.text !==""){daylistView.currentItem.notetaking.text= title.text}
                       else{}

                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

The problem I am facing is that `ListView` `daylistView` when I run the app is not defined inside the `Window` `inputWin` so I can not use the code in the window (bidirectional binding between `title.text` and `daylistView.currentItem.notetaking.text` is broken and `daylistView.currentIndex` is null).
I tried to expose `daylistView` as property but listview continues not to be defined.
How to make this listview be defined?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This makes sense, because you are creating multiple instances of the `daylistView`, so it is undefined which one you want.

You can however expose the `ListView` as property in the root delegate and use it through `ListView.currentItem`, given that you set `currentIndex` on the `dayCalendar` `ListView`

```
ListView{
    id: dayCalendar

    delegate: Item {
        id: calDelegate
        property int calIndex: index
        property var dayList: daylistView
        
        ListView {
            id: daylistView

            delegate: Item {
                MouseArea {
                    onClicked: {
                        dayCalendar.currentIndex = calDelegate.calIndex
                        daylistView.currentIndex = index
                        ...
                    }
                }
            }
        } 
    }
```

Inside the loaded qml:

```
TextField {
    id:title
    text: dayCalendar.currentItem.dayList.currentItem.notetaking.text
}
```

Comment: Yes.I followed your answer and it works except `daylistView.currentIndex`.How must be expressed in loaded qml?

Comment: if you want to get it from the loaded qml, it would be `dayCalendar.currentItem.dayList.currentIndex`

Comment: Thank you .It is working perfectly.But something last.Now  when I close the loaded window  everything is messed up .I mean the `currentIndex` of `daylistView` inside the view  it is not working. I can not  change anymore the index and of course the display of the view.The view it shows the current date but it does not change anymore when i choose another day.

Comment: I don't entirely understand, but try `property alias hourTime: hourweeklistviewLabel.text`, this way you will actually edit the text of the TextField instead of overwriting the binding

Comment: I am sorry that i did not explain clearly in the above comment what is the problem.I am talking about `dayCalendar.currentIndex` and not `daylistView.currentIndex`.The answer you gave is correct and the code is working until I close the window from loader .Then the `dayCalendar` listview  does not work.It is frozen and is not changing  view.If you want to help then the code for the two listviews is in the below link: https://gist.github.com/cgiannakidis70/37ac6f6aed0274c2408f9414c1afe1f9                   Thank you

Comment: @cgiannakidis I left a note on your gist